# Error while processing Pdf?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am getting following error while pdf is processed i get following error
[image]

From searching I found that this is caused by ghost script maybe due to transparency in embedded images but I am not exactly sure.So can somebody help me to find exactly what in pdf is causing this problem ?Is this is due to transparency in embedded images or something else?
I am using imagemagick.

Comment: which versions of Ghostscript and Imagemagick your using ?

Comment: Looks like its probably a broken PDF file to me, given that the error is a rangecheck (at least, I think it is, its extremely hard to read the image). At a guess there's a problem with a font, possibly a CIDFont.

Comment: @KenS when i opened that PDF first time in adobe reader it asked me to install a plugin.After installing that I was able to see that PDF.I exactly don't remember what plugin I installed. I will get back to you after reproducing that

Comment: @user1283633 Imagemagick version is 6.8.5  and ghostScript is 8.7

Comment: The current version of Ghostscript is 9.10, 8.7 is more than 3 years old, I suggest you try a newer version. I've never had Acrobat ask me to install any kind of plugin though, however, maybe you hadn't installed support for Far Eastern languages (which I always install), give that the error appears to be with a CIDFont that would explain the need to install extra components.

Comment: @user1283633 I will try new version and get back to you as soon as possible .So I suppose that problem is due to CIDFonts

Comment: @user1283633 new version worked for me and processing that PDF file.Thanks

Comment: @DhruvPal as a last tip i recommend using Ghostscript version 9.06 as the latest versions are not stable for me and for other people i know